# how do i get <p>value use python3 and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I use python3 and beactifulsop filter a html, In this html,
`<p><span><a href="/packages/symfony/symfony/stats" rel="nofollow">Installs</a>:</span>21 803 987</p>`

I want to get the number `21803987`,I use
`soup.text.strip()` it returns`Installs:21 803 987`
this is not my want,some has some idea?Thx!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> h = '<p><span><a href="/packages/symfony/symfony/stats" rel="nofollow">Installs</a>:</span>21 803 987</p>'
>>> s = BeautifulSoup(h, 'lxml')
>>> a = s.p.find(text=True, recursive=False)
>>> a
'21\u2009803\u2009987'
```

Answer (score 0):

The element p has all the text: "Installs:21 803 987", that's right.

To get only 21803987

```
soup.text.split(":")[-1].strip()
```

Comment: it works!But i still want to know weather there is a way that use beautifulsoup method find or select?,because if there were not ':',what should I do?

Comment: I repeat myself, The element P contains all the text in p and p children's (like <a>element). You will have to be able to manage text doing things like this and probably a bit more harder using Regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [strings](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=strings#strings-and-stripped-strings) attribute to access all the individual strings in the `p` tag. Then just grab the one you need (the last one):

```
list(soup.p.strings)[-1]
```

Or, more efficiently:

```
for text in soup.p.strings:
    pass
print(text)
```